# How to define different functions for ticks based on zoom level

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, interactive

I have a data analysis plot where the x-axis contains dates. The plot is supposed to be interactive, and what I want to do is the following:
As you zoom in more and more, I want the graph to (each point at a greater zoom)

- Show only year ticks
- Show only month ticks
- Show only day ticks
- Limit the resolution at days

The best solution I have found so far to my problem is using

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(dateticks))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(12)) #limits ticks
fig.autofmt_xdate() #rotates strings
```

Where "dateticks" is a function that returns the date string based on the x value (e.g. "18-3-2018")

This solution limits the total ticks on screen at a time, and makes new ones appear when you zoom in, but it shows "random" dates, and when the plot is zoomed out, you don't know where the year intervals are. Moreover if you zoom in past the day resolution, it will add extra ticks with the same day.

I only started coding in September 2018 but I love it! Can someone help?

[Here is a plot of my real code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fHGQ.png)
, and here is a code that reproduces my current situation:

```py
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter,MaxNLocator

def dateticks(dayssince00,pos):
    start=datetime.date(2000,1,1)
    new= start+datetime.timedelta(days=dayssince00)
    return "{}-{}-{}".format(new.day, new.month, new.year)

def graph():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

    days=[x for x in range(1000)]
    func=[x**2 for x in days]
    plt.plot(days,func)

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(dateticks))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(12)) #limits ticks
    fig.autofmt_xdate() #rotates strings

    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

graph()
```

Comment: It's interactive in the sense that you can zoom in, not more than that, and what I'm having trouble with are the ticks. Should I still use Bokeh for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The exact specified zooming behaviour is maybe a bit hard to accomplish, but the defaults are pretty close to it.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dateticks(dayssince00):
    start=datetime.date(2000,1,1)
    new= start+datetime.timedelta(days=dayssince00)
    return new

def graph():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

    day_num = list(range(1000))
    days = [dateticks(x) for x in day_num]
    func = [x**2 for x in day_num]
    plt.plot(days,func)

    fig.autofmt_xdate() #rotates strings

    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

graph()
```

Comment: I tried this and it shows all ticks at the same time; what I need is for most to be hidden until you zoom in more.

Comment: No it doesn't show all at the same time. At any zoomlevel it shows a useful number of ticks.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't edit the "return new" part. This is definitely a big improvement, thanks!

Comment: I am not able to fully implement it into my code because there are parts where I add a straight horizontal line that depends on the x value, but in this case it gets plotted close to the year 0

Comment: It gets plotted at the coordinates you give it.